# Autoscaling of IO bound Dataflow streaming jobs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I am in the middle of designing a component to load CSV files arrives on GCS bucket into BQ tables.
Since our requirements involves inserting additional columns,I have come up with the following design using Dataflow Streaming job.
[image]

**1]** CSV file arrives on GCS bucket

**2]** GCS object creation event is sent to a pub/sub topic.
These events are consumed by the 'GCS-BQ Loader' Dataflow streaming.

**2a]** Looking at the meta-data attached in GCS Object, decide the BQ table name,settings..etc
and calculate values for new columns (lot_num and batch)

**3]** Using BigqueryAPI, a temporary external table is created for the CSV file.

**4]** Using BigqueryAPI, query is executed to insert data from BQ external table into the final BQ table.This step is done because additional columns(lot_num,batch) needs to be added to the final table.
Finally the temporary external is deleted.

Depend on the metadata attached in GCS object, we expect to have around 1000 BQ tables. These CSV files range from couple of kilobytes to ~1Gb.

I have following **questions** regarding this design:

1. This process is IO bound (rather than CPU bound), since BQ API calls are blocking.
   In this case, these blocking calls will block the Dataflow threads.Will this impact the performance?
2. How does Dataflow autoscaling will work in this case?
   From the docs:

> Dataflow scales based on the parallelism of a pipeline. The
> parallelism of a pipeline is an estimate of the number of threads
> needed to most efficiently process data at any given time.

What kind of metric Dataflow use for auto-scaling for these kind of IO bound processes?

Is it the number of unacknowledged pub/sub messages in the buffer?

3. Is Dataflow suitable for this kind of IO bound processing? Or a plain Java app running on GKE(k8s) is more suitable for this case ?

Comment: interesting use case. how do you figure out the lot_num and batch column values? could you do it from within the Dataflow pipeline? Copying Data from one table to another in BQ has a very low limit. You could instead add the lot_num and batch data within your Dataflow pipeline, and use Beam's `BigQueryIO.write` transform to write the data to BQ with very high throughput.

Comment: @Pablo yes, those values lot_num and 'batch' values are generated inside the Dataflow job looking at the GCS Object meta-data. But when using TextIO.read() and BigQueryIO.write, file content of the CSV file flows through the Dataflow job right ? I wanted to avoid this, thats why I wanted to create an external-table and generate the final table using BQ Query, where there file content flows internally between BQ and GCS.

Comment: I see. Yes, you're correct that with TextIO.read, the whole data of each file goes through the pipeline. I believe that in this case, you may be better off using a cloud function to perform all the BQ API calls, since you probably don't need the large scaling capabilities of Dataflow - but consider that you may end up making too many BQ API calls and then may have to switch to Dataflow to use TextIO

Comment: @Pablo thanks, I first considered using Cloud Function, however it has max 7min timeout limit.We might have some cases that BQ query take more than 7mins. However, do you know how Dataflow will behaves when threads are blocked for IO calls like calling the BQ blocking API ? how it will effect the auto-scaling ?

Comment: autoscaling is affected by the backlog in your pubsub topic. if the backlog is not large, then the job will not see the need to scale up.